# Coral.ai Camera is connected and detected by Dev Board, but snapshot is not working

Tags: google-coral, pycoral

The that come with coral kit is connected to the Dev Board, as you can see by the command bellow:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
i.MX6S_CSI (platform:30a90000.csi1_bridge):
    /dev/video0
```

But when I run snapshot I get this:

```
Cannot find ov5645 CSI camera, check that your camera is connected
```

I already tried looking at Coral's documentation but can't seem to find the solution. Is there any step I'm missing?